# WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04: Apache is slow

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, apache-http-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL 2 Ubuntu 20.04 in Windows 10, on a i5-10210U Processor (8 GB RAM) and, generally, when working directly in Ubuntu environment, it's very fast. But from a browser in Windows, Apache isn't. Even a simple html with a simple string takes about 2 seconds to load (if not cached).

I've read about performance issues when from WSL I try to access to Windows files, but in this case, I'm accessing directly to Ubuntu WSL2, so it shouldn't be so slow... am I right?

I've also tried a wget in WSL 2 and it downloads instantly, so it's not an Apache problem but, maybe, a network problem or misconfiguration between Windows and WSL?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6366#issuecomment-749448727

Comment: My projects are under WSL2 file system.

Comment: What are the settings of you used network adapter? (external/internal) And bandwidth management isn't set in the Ubuntu VM settings (in the network-page)?

Comment: Sorry I went back to Windows Apache without WSL2... I had other issues so I give up.